# Loading vhosts from MySQL in lighttpd

Tags: mysql, lighttpd, vhosts

I have a MySQL table with a list of domains added by a PHP script. It is literally just a simple list of domains, and all the domains will point to the exact same location.

How can I get lighttpd to load these domains? It would be good if there was some built in functionality to automatically check the table for new additions, or just check all the vhosts each time someone loads a page.

If not, I could run a script that restarts lighttpd when it detects a vhost change. But whatever I do, lighttpd needs to load the vhosts from the database and keep them updated fairly frequently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs:ModMySQLVhost - that could help you out ;)